# Spring transactions and their interaction with the synchronized keyword

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, transactions, spring-jdbc

I have a DAO class that uses Spring JDBC to access an SQLite database. I have declared transactions on the DAO methods themselves since my service layer never combines queries in a transaction.

Since I use a few worker threads in parallel but only one thread can update an SQLite DB at the same time, I use `synchronized` to serialize access to the DAO.

At first, I synchronized externally from my service class, for example:

```
synchronized (dao) {
    dao.update(...);
}
```

Then, I figured I might as well get rid of the external synchronization and put `synchronized` on the DAO method itself:

```
public synchronized void update(...) {
    // Spring JDBC calls here
}
```

The strange thing is: my queries now take twice the time they used to!

Why?

Comment: They take twice the time since you moved the synchronized from the service method to the DAO method?

Answer (score 1):

Well, one difference is obvious:

```
synchronized (dao) {
    // here you are synchronizing on the transactional proxy
}

public synchronized void update(...) {
    // and here you are synchronizing on the target class, *inside* the proxy
}
```

What the implications of this are depends on your other code, but that's the obvious difference.

Comment: I'm guessing that in the **latter** case when the DAO's `update()` method returns, 1) the `synchronized` block within it ends and 2) the transactional proxy commits its transaction so it is effectively still trying to update the SQLite DB concurrently, i.e. exactly that what I was trying to prevent. Does that sound plausible?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your update method or entire class is annotated with Transactional or wrapped by transactional proxy through other means. This means whenever you call dao's method, the transactional proxy retrieves db connection from the pool, opens a transaction and then calls the real method.

In your first scenario you synchronize before even reaching the proxy, thus no connection and transaction magic happens. In the second scenario you do the waiting call after that.

If there are multiple threads trying to perform simultaneous updates there will be only one doing the update and the rest will be first opening new connections and then waiting for dao access. As a consequence instead of one connection being constantly reused you will have multiple connections in use. I can only guess how this really affects the performance but you can experiment with different pool size starting with one.

Comment: I use a BoundedExecutor with a bound of 4 so there are 4 threads doing calculations and then updating the DB in parallel. I did some tests with a C3p0 connection pool and these are the results: 1 connection in the pool -> 7 seconds, 2 conns -> 13s, 3 conns -> 13s, 10 conns -> 13s and 256 conns-> 13s. So performance actually degrades when the connection pool size is greater than one. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are doing updates only, you can try to get rid of synchronized and use pool with one connection. As for multiple connections performing worse than a single one is quite clear. You in fact allow a single transaction at time only so you don't need overhead of managing those extra connections. Although I would rather expect the time increase up to 4 connections then stay unchanged.